# intersected lines in forecast plots by group in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

In my dataset i performed the forecast divided by group(store).
Here it is

```
df=structure(list(Store = c(173L, 173L, 173L, 173L, 173L, 173L, 
173L, 173L, 173L, 173L, 173L, 173L, 173L, 173L, 174L, 174L, 174L, 
174L, 174L, 174L, 174L, 174L, 174L, 174L, 174L, 174L, 174L, 174L, 
173L, 173L, 173L, 173L, 173L, 173L, 173L, 173L, 173L, 173L, 173L, 
173L, 173L, 173L, 174L, 174L, 174L, 174L, 174L, 174L, 174L, 174L, 
174L, 174L, 174L, 174L, 174L, 174L, 173L, 173L, 173L, 173L, 173L, 
173L, 173L, 173L, 173L, 173L, 173L, 173L, 173L, 173L, 174L, 174L, 
174L, 174L, 174L, 174L, 174L, 174L, 174L, 174L, 174L, 174L, 174L, 
174L), DayOfWeek = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), Date = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("15.07.2015", "16.07.2015", "17.07.2015"
), class = "factor"), Sales = structure(c(27L, 12L, 16L, 18L, 
9L, 4L, 26L, 23L, 10L, 19L, 7L, 20L, 25L, 5L, 17L, 2L, 11L, 8L, 
3L, 22L, 15L, 14L, 28L, 6L, 1L, 24L, 13L, 21L, 27L, 12L, 16L, 
18L, 9L, 4L, 26L, 23L, 10L, 19L, 7L, 20L, 25L, 5L, 17L, 2L, 11L, 
8L, 3L, 22L, 15L, 14L, 28L, 6L, 1L, 24L, 13L, 21L, 27L, 12L, 
16L, 18L, 9L, 4L, 26L, 23L, 10L, 19L, 7L, 20L, 25L, 5L, 17L, 
2L, 11L, 8L, 3L, 22L, 15L, 14L, 28L, 6L, 1L, 24L, 13L, 21L), .Label = c("10318.344", 
"10725.268", "10765.647", "13546.236", "3418.328", "3939.406", 
"4089.442", "4377.643", "5196.012", "5487.437", "5778.296", "6200.403", 
"6216.929", "6331.589", "6404.693", "6472.833", "6693.678", "6751.922", 
"6770.161", "7510.433", "7736.447", "7743.879", "8107.569", "8119.046", 
"9087.104", "9326.839", "9718.452", "9855.327"), class = "factor"), 
    Promo = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), LinearRegressionForecast = structure(c(22L, 
    9L, 15L, 14L, 8L, 1L, 26L, 20L, 6L, 17L, 3L, 18L, 25L, 2L, 
    11L, 27L, 7L, 5L, 24L, 13L, 10L, 12L, 23L, 4L, 28L, 21L, 
    16L, 19L, 22L, 9L, 15L, 14L, 8L, 1L, 26L, 20L, 6L, 17L, 3L, 
    18L, 25L, 2L, 11L, 27L, 7L, 5L, 24L, 13L, 10L, 12L, 23L, 
    4L, 28L, 21L, 16L, 19L, 22L, 9L, 15L, 14L, 8L, 1L, 26L, 20L, 
    6L, 17L, 3L, 18L, 25L, 2L, 11L, 27L, 7L, 5L, 24L, 13L, 10L, 
    12L, 23L, 4L, 28L, 21L, 16L, 19L), .Label = c("10672.724", 
    "2286.724", "2940.339", "3038.273", "3265.624", "3387.729", 
    "3475.001", "3568.385", "4527.949", "5042.683", "5131.816", 
    "5196.835", "5204.855", "5239.113", "5572.545", "5605.564", 
    "5656.971", "6216.276", "6510.814", "6749.251", "6901.256", 
    "7248.194", "7310.538", "7549.539", "7585.489", "7842.506", 
    "8371.118", "8487.823"), class = "factor"), Type = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Forecast", "obser"
    ), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Store", "DayOfWeek", "Date", 
"Sales", "Promo", "LinearRegressionForecast", "Type"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-84L))
```

There is column type. It is indicates what is type (forecast or obser).
Forecast was made for each store separately.
I need create for each store(173 and 174 separately) the forecast plot where forecast and obser lines are intersected (for date and sales variables)
How to do it?

## Desired plot

[image]

sorry for my paint

Comment: There's only one day in `Date` column. Can you give an example of figure you want to make?

Comment: @PoGibas, right, it is just example,that why , only 1 date, i edited post with desired plot, sorry for my paint

Comment: Can you add one more day? Also, why do you need `LinearRegressionForecast` column

Comment: @PoGibas, i added new two days. DayOfWeek ,Promo LinearRegressionForecast are not needed.

Comment: What should be done with multiple observations (ie, there are multiple sales per same store, Date and Type)

Comment: @PoGibas, just ignore it.  all date in axis x 15.07,16.07 and so on

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176060/discussion-between-pogibas-and-d-joe).

Comment: If there are extra columns in your dataset that aren't relevant to the question, it's helpful to remove them from the sample you post here. That way we're only working with what's important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bunch of things in the data set that need to be done:

Firstly factors need to be numeric and dates need to be date objects. I have done this using `mutate`

Then we can group by `Store` and `Date` and use `summarise` to find the total daily sales and total daily forecast value

Then use `gather` to make the table tidy and then we have our `clean_df`

Then simply use ggplot to make your plot[image]

```
clean_df <- df %>% 
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date, format = "%d.%m.%Y"),
         Sales = as.numeric(Sales),
         LinearRegressionForecast = as.numeric(LinearRegressionForecast)) %>% 
  select(Date,Sales, LinearRegressionForecast,Store) %>% 
  group_by(Store, Date) %>% 
  summarise(total_daily_sales = sum(Sales, na.rm = T),
            total_daily_forecast = sum(LinearRegressionForecast, na.rm = T)) %>% 
  gather(type, value, -Date, -Store)

clean_df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Date, y = value, col = type)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  facet_wrap(~Store)
```

Code is here